# How can I undo the "Do Not Ask Again" for bluetooth contacts?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, security, bluetooth

When I first connected my phone (Samsung Galaxy S II) to a bluetooth device, I was prompted that the device wanted to access my contacts.

I mistakenly clicked <kbd>Do Not Ask Again</kbd> but I want to undo that. Is there a way to do this?

<sup>I'm running ice cream sandwich.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure as I have no BT devices in use -- but most likely you should find something in the settings at "Wireless & Networking -> Bluetooth-Settings". At the end of that screen there's a section named "Bluetooth devices" -- here your other BT-Device should be listed. As a last resort, you could simply remove it from the list -- which will require you to repeat the pairing process.

Comment: Izzy, I did try that, unfortunately with no luck. I'm thinking I might have set that to be a permanent setting for all devices. I'll try again though - maybe I didn't fully remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Jeff, I doubt such a global setting exists (to make that default for all devices), as that would be too dangerous from a security standpoint. But check all items in that menu, it's the first place to look for -- and it shouldn't require a factory reset ;). If I happen to find a second possible place, I'll try to update it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the device in discovery mode before you sync it on your phone. I ran into the same issue and that is how I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, go to

1. Settings -> Apps
2. slide to "All" category and choose "Bluetooth Share"
3. scroll down a bit, click "clear defaults"

This way you can reset any "do not ask me again" or "use this as default" of any app.